# ngClass switch between li background-color angular 2

Tags: css, angular

Actual behavior
When I click any submenu all submenus change the color.

Desired behavior
When a submenu1 is clicked only that one should change the color, when submenu2 is clicked only that one should change and submenu1(and any other submenu that isn't submenu2 even the submenus inside any other main menu) should get back to it´s original color.

What I´ve is the following;

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="mainmenu">
        <li class="dropdown-content" (click)="onClickHome()"><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li [class]="hideUsability" *ngFor="let menu of entities">
            <a [ngClass]="{'entities-list__title--active' : menu.isOpen}" (click)="onClickMenu(menu)">{{menu.entity_name}}</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content" >
                <li [ngClass]="{'btn-add': !menu.isOpen, 'btn-remove': menu.isOpen}" [hidden]="!menu.isOpen" (click)="onClickSubmenu(value.value_id)" *ngFor="let value of menu.values"><a href='javascript:void(0)'>{{value.value_name}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Component (Angular 2)

```
    onClickHome(){
        this.closeAllMenus();
        this.router.navigate(['welcome'], { skipLocationChange: true});
    }

    onClickMenu(menu){
        if (!menu.isOpen){
            this.closeAllMenus();
        }
        menu.isOpen = !menu.isOpen;
    }

    onClickSubmenu(value_id: number){
        if(value_id == 2){
            this.router.navigate(['welcome/metrics.html'], { skipLocationChange: true});
        } else{
            this.router.navigate(['welcome/extractor.html'], { skipLocationChange: true});
        }
    }

    closeAllMenus(){
        this.entities.forEach((menu) =>{
            menu.isOpen = false;
        });
    }
```

CSS:

```
.btn-add {
    background-color: red;
} 

.btn-remove {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLUTION

This is a cleaner code, with [ngClass]="{active: value.highlighted}" I can chose the style I want to be applied on the desired item if it's active (true/false), also my menu is a dropdown when cursor hover on menu display the submenus when pointing somewhere else submenus hide and with this approach I could make the menu stay open showing submenus and highlighting the proper submenu.

To point out I'm working with two *ngFor (an array of objects with array of objects).

HTML

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="mainmenu">
        <li class="dropdown-content" (click)="onClickHome()"><a [class]="activeMenuHome">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngFor="let menu of entities"><a>{{menu.entity_name}}</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content" [hidden]="!menu.isOpen">
                <li *ngFor="let value of menu.values">
                    <a [ngClass]="{active: value.highlighted}" (click)="onClickSubMenu(menu, value)">{{value.value_name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

COMPONENT (Angular 2)

```
    onClickHome(){
        this.activeMenuHome="active";
        this.activeSubmenu="";
        this.closeAllMenus();
        this.highlightedOff();
        this.router.navigate(['welcome'], { skipLocationChange: true});
    }

    onClickSubMenu(menu, value){
        this.activeMenuHome="";
        this.closeAllMenus();
        this.highlightedOff();
        menu.isOpen = true;
        value.highlighted = true;
        //More code to navigate
    }

    closeAllMenus(){
        this.entities.forEach((menu) =>{
            menu.isOpen = false;
        });
    }

    highlightedOff(){
        this.entities.forEach((values) =>{
            values.values.forEach((value) => {
                value.highlighted = false;
            });
        });
    }
```

CSS

```
.active {
    background-color: #C8E0F6 !important;
    color: #151921 !important;
}
```

Comment: Using CSS to avoid utilizing Angular is a workaround that avoids the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from menu.isOpen value change.

```
....   
  <li [class]="hideUsability" *ngFor="let menu of entities; let i = index">
          <a [ngClass]="{'entities-list__title--active' : isOpen = i}" (click)="onClickMenu(i)">{{menu.entity_name}}</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-content" >
            <li [ngClass]="{'btn-add': isOpen!=i, 'btn-remove': isOpen==i}" [hidden]="isOpen!=i" (click)="onClickSubmenu(value.value_id)" *ngFor="let value of menu.values"><a href='javascript:void(0)'>{{value.value_name}}</a></li>
          </ul>
   </li>
....

    onClickMenu(index){
       this.isOpen=index
    }
```

Comment: I @Vega, I wasn't able to implement your changes, tried but what you proposed moved functionality already working, could you please check again and give me a little feedback? (By the way completely newbie on Angular)

Comment: I am trying to make a plunker. Can you provide 'entities'  example

Comment: Until then, I saw that   in <li [ngClass]="{'btn-add': !menu.isOpen, 'btn-remove': menu.isOpen}" [hidden]="!menu.isOpen" .......> the class btn-add will not be applied as <li> would be hidden by [hidden] condition. So leave one or an other

Comment: in  onClickMenu(menu) it should be this.entities[menu.id].isOpen = true/false and so you should change the function signature to onClickMenu(id) and in the template call  (click)="onClickMenu(menu.id)"

Comment: But this will be easier with a plunker and would need a sample of 'entities' structure with some example data in it.

Comment: Hi Vega, sorry for the delay, here is the entity {"entities":[{"entity_id":202,"hierarchy_bol":0,"values":[{"value_id":2,"entities":[]}]},{"entity_id":203,"hierarchy_bol":0,"values":[{"value_id":3,"entities":[]}]}]}

Comment: That´s what I'm having hard time, any child/submenu clicked of parent menu must be highlighted and shown the rest of child/submenus of any other parent must get back to it's original color and hide.

Comment: I made a plunker. I had to change entities structure and content to make it work. It may not exactely what you are trying to achieve but you get the idea : https://plnkr.co/edit/B2d43ENJTTVVGgmHcZoX?p=preview

Comment: I appreciate your help, however all submenus stay colored and only the clicked one must color/highlighted, will try to figure it out with your example, thank you!

Comment: I know, this is because you need a unique key to identify the <li> and I wasn't able to change the model data without you knowing what's going on. You need to add a unique code or combine entity_id+value_id to identifiy each option, but the strategy stays the same! Tell me if you need more guidance